# Why did Amanda Grayson marry Sarek?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, character-motivation

I'm curious how the marriage of Spock's parents came about.  How did they meet?  What drew Amanda to Sarek?  I can understand why Sarek, as the Vulcan ambassador to Earth, might find it logical to marry a human woman, but do we know anything about her side of the story?

Comment: Who wouldn't want to marry the ambassador for an entire world? So what if he has pointy ears and green blood?

Comment: When trying to come up with an answer I found another question: why, after Amanda died, did Sarek marry another human? Is he some sort of pervert terraphile?

Comment: Amanda married Sarek because she was part of [Team Spock](http://i269.photobucket.com/albums/jj59/sexy-sesshy/Team_Spock_by_imbatman1313.jpg).

Comment: Where da human women at?

Comment: @SystemDown - She's got Vulcan fever, she's got Vulcan Fever. She's gone green-blood crazy, he's gone white-human hazy...; http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nNbM781v7M0

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Within the TV series, it's pretty clear that Amanda Grayson's attraction for Sarek is in no small part led by her overall [admiration for Vulcan culture](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/44.htm);

> **AMANDA:** *You don't understand the Vulcan way, Captain. It's logical. **It's a better way than ours.** But it's not easy. It has
>   kept Spock and Sarek from speaking as father and son for eighteen
>   years.*

On top of that, it's obvious that despite the Vulcan aim to hide their emotions behind a façade of logic, that she is very well aware of [his affection for her](http://www.startrek.com/watch_video/vid-make-journeytobabel-fontana), something he finally admits in his failing years suffering from Bendii syndrome;

> **Sarek** : *Amanda... I could have given you so much more. I wanted to show you
>   tenderness. But it is not our way. Spock...Amanda did you know?*

As to how they met, there's a brief mention in [one of the TOS episodes](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/25.htm) that Amanda was a teacher. In the (non-canon) [Vulcan Academy Murders](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Vulcan_Academy_Murders) book, it's revealed that she was teaching at the Vulcan Science Academy on Earth, tasked with educating recent Vulcan arrivals about Earth culture. The Academy was part of the Vulcan embassy and as Ambassador his duties included teaching and lecturing. Because of this, they were both in regular contact with and ultimately ended up marrying after a brief courtship.

As System Down mentioned in his comment below; the non-canon book "[Spock's World](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spock%27s_World)" also has a slightly different story about how they met - I've edited it for brevity;

> Quite shortly thereafter, he met Amanda Greyson.
>
> It was, of course, in the line of business. She was involved with a
>   Federation program intended to develop a universal translator, and
>   Sarek was happy to have his linguistics department assist her such an
>   instrument could only be a tremendous breakthrough, in a world where
>   until now wars might be caused or averted by the mistranslation of a
>   term. She did not make any particular impression on him when he saw
>   her first-a handsome woman, tall for her people, with wise eyes.
>   Later, he found that she reminded him of TPau, in some odd fashion,
>   though he had trouble identifying exactly what the likeness was.
>
> They met fairly often after that. Sarek's English was more flexible and
>   idiomatic than any of his staff's. That was the excuse. But increasingly
>   he found himself delighting in having a friend. He had had few, on
>   Vulcan from a very young age, his work had possessed him. During his
>   earlier posting here, he had been on the move all the time, even when
>   working-gathering data, rarely staying mentally in the same place for
>   very long. But now, in his early maturity, he felt a little more
>   settled, and that settlement found great satisfaction in the
>   expression of friendship.
>
> There came a time when the day seemed somehow incomplete if she had
>   not called him and asked him about something, or told him what she was
>   doing.

Comment: I highly recommend reading Diane Duane's "Spock's World". Not canon perhaps, but a very nice look into Vulcan society, including Sarek and Amanda's courtship.

Comment: @SystemDown - Yes, as with most non-canon novels there's a bit of a mis-match between the events of the book and other books. I still though it was worth adding to my answer since it specifically refers to their meeting.

Comment: Diane Duane's "Spock's World" was an excellent addition to the world of Star Trek. Too bad it is not considered canon. She is quite a prolific writer and resides in Ireland now, County Wicklow to be exact.

Comment: @SystemDown - I recommend reading *any* of Diane Duane's Trek fiction. The Rihannsu series (Particularly "My Enemy, My Ally") remain my favorite Trek books to this day. (After reading probably 75% of the Trek published fiction out there).