# Why did Sarek marry another human after Spock's mother died?

Tags: star-trek, vulcan

Inspired by a comment in [Why did Amanda Grayson marry Sarek?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54332/why-did-amanda-grayson-marry-sarek)

I was wondering if there's a canon or even expanded universe reason that indicates *why*, (after the death of his first wife) Sarek would marry [another human](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Perrin)?

Comment: I'm tempted to say it's because no self-respecting Vulcan woman would marry him afterwards.

Comment: Or he knew about his impending illness and he knew a Human woman would be more sympathetic and stick by him.

Comment: Or it was logical because he was an ambassador and humans tends to get along with all the other species.

Comment: @muistooshort Is this sarcasm? If this be logic from Sarek, the disease manifests strongly.

Comment: @IhorSypko If your job is to interact with other species peacefully, it would help to have a gregarious mate to avoid being mentally boxed into only Vulcan ways of thinking. Sarek married a human originally because he was an ambassador to Earth, perhaps he found the near constant presence of a radically different point of view helpful to avoid tunnel vision.

Comment: "Vulcans typically only mate once every 7 years. Since this would probably be too rare for a human woman, it's very possible that his sexual appetites may have changed after spending time with his first wife. I can see him becoming used to having (ahem) relations substantially more often than would be normal for a Vulcan male. A Vulcan woman would see this as gross perversion whereas a human woman would be far more understanding." You obviously don't know my ex wife!

Comment: I felt that my answer was pretty comprehensive, with references to the show, films and novels. Is there anything else you'd like to see before considering an acceptance?

Comment: Desperate for rep? Sorry, I did leave this one hanging...

Comment: @HorusKol - I just thought that I'd make today a 'pickup' day and sort out some spring-cleaning. That includes chasing up unaccepted questions where my answer score is the highest.

Comment: As they say on Vulcan: "Once you go human there's no logical reason for going back."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's no "in-canon" description of why Sarek would have married another human (e.g. as opposed to another Vulcan) but we can certainly speculate on some *possible* reasons;

### He's damaged goods

His arranged marriage (to a Vulcan princess no less) did lead to a [child](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Sybok) but **not** a wedding. He describes [Amanda Grayson](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Amanda_Grayson) as his "first wife".

It's certainly possible that this was a sufficiently shocking event in Vulcan high-society as to prevent him from securing another Vulcan wife of appropriate standing. Since humans have no place in the Vulcan aristocracy, there's no shame incurred in his marrying an outsider.

### It's logical, given his position.

He describes his marriage to Amanda as "[logical](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/44.htm)", especially given his position as Ambassador to Earth. As a Federation Ambassador, it would also make good sense to have a human wife since humans seem to be an important and influential group in the UFP.

### Vulcans couples seem to have substantially less sex (on average) than human couples.

Vulcans often go for years between sex acts, supplementing time apart with prayer and meditation and only indulging in sexual acts, when together, very sparingly. Only having sex once or twice a year would probably be frustratingly rare for a newly-wed human woman and it's very possible that his sexual *appetites* may have changed after spending time with his first wife. I can see him becoming used to having (ahem) *relations* substantially more often than would be normal for a Vulcan male. A Vulcan woman would see this as gross perversion whereas a human woman would be far more understanding.

### He's poorly/unwell and doesn't want it disclosed.

Sarek has known for many years that he's at risk of Bendii Syndrome. Since this manifests in outbursts of **emotionality**, caring for him would be an amazingly difficult task for a Vulcan woman. By comparison, a human would view his actions as relatively routine.

### EU Canon

Within the EU canon, the TOS Comic : [Enter the Wolves](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Enter_the_Wolves) describes his courtship of Perrin Landover. The details bear a ***remarkable similarity*** to his courtship of Amanda Grayson;

> "Perrin was a xeno-linguist, who had met Vulcan Ambassador Sarek at a
>   diplomatic circa 2326. She had asked for and was granted an interview
>   with the ambassador, and the two met regularly during the following
>   year. Sarek surprised her by opening up about his loneliness following
>   the death of his wife, Amanda Grayson, and eventually asked her to
>   share his life."

Comment: The "He's poorly and doesn't want it disclosed" seems like it's missing a word. :)

Comment: @SeanDuggan Isn't that a common (if rather British) use of *poorly* though?

Comment: @muistooshort: Huh. Learn something new every day. I had never seen that used as an adjective, not an adverb.

Comment: @SeanDuggan - I shall plead guilty to being British.

Comment: +1 "Vulcans typically only mate once every 7 years."

Comment: @Richard: I feel like there's a lame joke to be made about your guilt being punished with unsweetened tea and stale crumpets, but I'm probably just reaching now. :) Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Vulcans don't **only** mate once every 7 years. They just **must** mate once every 7 years. They **can** mate more than that.

Answer (score -1):

Sarek married Perrin cos once you go Terran you don't go back lol Seriously he married her because he loved her, he confessed as much via Picard in the episode 'Sarek'. Also according to Tuvok the Vulcan male libido increases with age perhaps only a Human can keep up with them lol. (Vulcans can have sex whenever they want not just every 7 years)

Comment: Hi try adding some link "according to" .. according to what, where do you get your fact ?

Comment: The Star Trek episode 'Sarek' is my fact, watch the scene where Picard is sitting in a room full of Sarek's emotions.

Comment: Your the one giving the answer.. try adding a link in your answer.. your comment also remind me to tell you the visit the [help] on how to post a good answer and also take the [tour]

Comment: http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Sarek_(episode)

Comment: You want the link of the scene where Tuvok told a fellow officer that Vulcan libido increases with age, I believe its the same episode where he experienced Ponn Farr.

Comment: lol... Edit your answer if you wish to have some rep one day :P .. I'm just sayin this to help but if you wanna take it that way its fine with me.. Looking at your profil you seem to have a lot of downvoted answers. you should focus on one question and give it a good and detailed answer

Answer (score -3):

Did anyone ever think that he married another human because of Spock? That it would be easier on him that his stepmother was of Earth and therefore relate to him better? Geez people....

Comment: That's certainly an idea. Can you back it up with any actual evidence?